# How to set "type" in controller using Single Table Inheritance in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I am new to rails and trying to set the "type" of a subclass in my create controller.  How do I go about this? Here is my code:

Post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :name, :song_id, :user_id, :artist_id, :type
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

Picture.rb

```
class Picture < Post
end
```

And finally the controller:

```
def create
@picture = Post.new(params[:picture])
@picture.type = "Picture"
    if @picture.save
      redirect_to @artist, :notice => "Successfully posted picture."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't see why the code you have wouldn't work, it would be better to do

`@picture = Picture.new(params[:picture])`

`:type` will be automatically set to `"Picture"` if you do this.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try:

```
@picture = Post.new(params[:picture]).becomes(Picture)
```

here are the docs for that: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/becomes